# const keyword scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, constants

```
1. >>> const a = 2
2. >>> var a = 3
3. >>> a = 4
4. >>> a // print 2
```

Why the operation line 3 is allowed? const seems more "global" than without any keyword...

Comment: `const` defines a constant (in supporting browsers). Why would you expect to be able to change it?  JavaScript will not throw an exception if you try to change the value of a `const`, but will silently ignore your instruction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript

Comment: Note that `const` is part of [JavaScript™](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript), it is not part of [ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) and as zerkms says, it's availability is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [is just how `const` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) (or doesn't work):

> Creates a constant<sup>1</sup> that can be global or local to the function in which it is declared. *Constants follow the same scope rules as variables [.. and cannot share a name] with a function or a variable in the same scope.*
>
> Firefox [..] throws a TypeError if you redeclare<sup>2</sup> [which is different than re-assigning] a constant. **None of the major browsers produce any notices or errors<sup>2,3</sup> if you *assign* another value to a constant** [..] *but the reassignment is unsuccessful (only) in Firefox and Chrome (at least since version 20).*

Note that `const` is *not* part of the ECMAScript 5 specification and the JavaScript 1.5 semantics will be *re-defined* in ECMAScript 6.

Behavior *will* vary across browser implementations with respect to support and re-declaration/re-assignments semantics.

---

<sup>1</sup> In IE 9, using `const a = 2` results in

> "Syntax error"

<sup>2</sup> In FF 14, `const a = 2; var a = 3; a = 4; a`, when evaluated as a single program, results in

> TypeError: redeclaration of const a

which is *different* than executing each line one-at-a-time in the REPL. I *suspect* this is because `var` is *hoisted above* the `const` and because a const "cannot share a name with a function or variable in the same scope".

<sup>3</sup> In Chrome 21, `const a = 2; var a = 3; a = 4; a` evaluates to 2 with no warning or message.

Answer (score 32):

**`const` scope is defined as 'block scoped'** (the scope of which, is restricted to the block in which it is declared).

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> Constants are **block-scoped**, much like variables defined using the **let**
> statement. The value of a constant cannot change through
> re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

Regarding your specific issue:
First as comments said `const` is relevant in ES6. I don't know about you but i get (typing your line 2: `var a = 3;`): SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
so your example is not quite possible.

Comment: Good explanation!  In modern versions of Chrome (v65), this is correct.  In older versions, i.e., v48, this appears to be not how they implemented it.  I have made a jsbin for testing, v65 gives "abcdef...", v48 gives "aaaa", meaning const's were unchangeable, despite block-level: https://jsbin.com/vemaxeniho/edit?html,output  Thanks for posting!