# Define an array with const-like thing in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, constants

I want to do sth like this (c++):

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int array[SIZE];
```

but in JS. I'm using the `SIZE` value many times (for many arrays and later in the code) and I don't want to put many literals with the same value (in case I have to edit it later). I read somewhere that there's a `const` keyword in JS but it doesn't work in every browser (not sure if that's true but I want a universal solution). And the shorter/simpler the better! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` keyword is in fact non-standard, <strike>and only implemented by Mozilla</strike> therefore not guaranteed to work cross-browser (but apparently some browsers implement it, see the link on Bergi's answer). Just use a regular variable, and the uppercase name to indicate it's supposed to be a constant:

```
var SIZE = 5;
var arr = new Array(SIZE);
```

Note: if you pass anything other than a number to the `Array` constructor, it will create an array with `length` and the value you passed at index `0`. In that case, it's best to just use the literal notation (`var arr = ['foo']`). Also keep in mind that when you pass a number to the constructor, you're just setting the initial `length`, and it's always possible to add or remove elements after that.

Comment: Of course... I guess all arrays in JS are dynamic? Meaning that I can always use a variable (instead of const) and the array will create without a problem? :P

Comment: Exactly. And actually, the value you pass to the constructor is just the initial length, you can always add/remove elements after that.

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign a

```
var arr = new Array(5);
```

which initializes an array with a `length` property of `5` but no values (sparse array).

Declaring variable types as in C++ is not possible, as JS is a [loose typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing) language, also there are no arrays with a fixed length - `Array`s are more like lists. For the `const` keyword, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12272836/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.defineProperty(window, PI, {
    configurable: false,
    writeable: false,
    value: 3.1415
});

console.log(PI); // 3.1415

/* if 'use strict', the acts below would throw error */

PI = 0; // nothing happened

window.PI = 0; // nothing happened

delete window.PI;  // nothing happened

Object.defineProperty(window, PI, {
    configurable: true,
    writeable: true,
    value: 0
}); // nothing happened

console.log(PI); // 3.1415
```

array or object can also define its attributes as 'const' with

```
Object.defineProperties
```

but the fastest way is

```
Object.freeze(obj_name)
```

but you have to ensure that the object itself is a 'const' then its attributes are in real safe