# Javascript: dealing with constants and cross-browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cross-browser, constants

Just read that [(`const`) Behavior will vary across browser implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272836/const-keyword-scope-in-javascript/12272877#12272877). The answer I pointed to is pretty old (2012) so, is it still so bad?

As I need cross browser compatibility in my project so should I avoid use of `const` keyword?

If 'yes' - how do I replace one?

**UPD:**

Just checked the description on the [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). And YES: looks like it is that bad...

[image]

Comment: this is a question related to ES6 const and porting those references to browsers that don't support that. Therefore, you'll need a transpiler (`babel`) to ensure ES5 browsers like IE 11 (and below) can run your js.

Comment: @siam As I understand variable defined with `const` has some protection. So I'd say that it would be a good idea to use ones... If it is not possible - I don't see any serious reasons to avoid `var`. Could you post this as an answer to let me accept one? Thanks!

Comment: @siam `var` is not equivalent to `let` or `const`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha did I say its equivalent? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` isn't available in old browsers (I'm looking at you, IE, Safari).

If you want to play safe, and you have no build step (Babel, TypeScript, etc), use only `var`. Both Babel and TypeScript will compile your `const`s and `let`s to `var`s. So if you use any of those tools, you can use `const` and `let` freely.

Be mindful that `var` is not strictly equivalent to either `let` or `const`. (`var` is hoisted, and has a different scope).

Also, if you don't care about IE or Safari, you can pretty much use `const` without a build tool.

Comment: @deceze Try Safari on iOS devices still on the market today, and tell me if it still applies.

Comment: That's an important qualifier. :)

Comment: @deceze I did say "old browsers"

Comment: As I understand - `const` will not work on Android which is pretty bad I think.

Comment: @VladaKatlinskaya Right, so use the other options (stick to `var`, or add Babel)

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) instead of [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) to support old browsers. (** remember `var` isn't equivalent to `const` to some extent)
and to protect a `var` from being changed you can just put it inside a private scope instead of global. (so it'll work partly like a `const`)