# Hoisting for const

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am having doubt in following code how const is working. below code runs without error and showing Z is 8 . what my expectation is it should throw refrence error z is already defined . Can anyone explain this

```js
(function() {
  {
    const z = 4;

    if (true) {
      const z = 8;
      console.log("Z is " + z);
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: const variables may be declared and initialized in a new lexical environment, i.e. in a new block.

Comment: `const` and `let` are not hoisted. In addition, here you're shadowing the outer `z`. Hence, it logs `8`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) or [const keyword scope in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12272836/215552) or [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/215552)

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with hoisting.

`const` (and `let`) are scoped to [the **block**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), not the function (`var` is scoped to the function).

The `if` block is a new scope so can have a new `const` with the same name (masking the one outside the `if`).

```js
(function() {
  {
    const z = 4;

    if (true) {
      const z = 8;
      console.log("Z inside the IF block is " + z);
    }

    console.log("Z outside the IF block is " + z);
  }
})()
```