# Reference Error const is not defined. I can't understand why

Tags: constants

I have a simple script like this

```
function importazione() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const wsd = ss.getSheetByName("morosi");
  wsd.getRange(2,1,1000,10).clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("importa");
  const max_riga = ws.getLastRow();
  var dati = ws.getRange(2, 1, max_riga-1, 6).getValues();
  
  dati.forEach(r => {                  
    scriviElenco({
      corso: r[0],
      ciclo: r[1],
      studente: r[2],
      status: r[4],
      id_matr: r[5]
    });
  });
}

function scriviElenco(passa) {
  if (passa.status === "NO PAGÓ") {    
    var daSplittare = passa.corso+"|"+passa.studente+"|"+passa.id_matr;
    var riga = [];
    riga = daSplittare.split("|");
    wsd.appendRow(riga);
  };
}
```

it returns this error on the last line:

> ReferenceError: wsd is not defined

I don't understand why wsd constant is not defined, I have much more complex scripts in which I use the same definitions and it works.
Could someone help me to understand please?

Comment: The const is scoped to the function you defined it in. If you need it available to multiple functions, define it outside of a function

Comment: Yes, I understand. Or I can insert the function scriviElenco inside the function importazione.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why wsd constant is not defined

`wsd` is not in scope within your second function, `scriviElenco()`; it is only in scope within `importazione()` - since [Javascript `const` definitions have block scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43963717/1593077). And this actually makes sense, because `wsd` is only set when you execute `importazione()`, and you can't expect it to have a valid value in the second function. So, you'll probably have to write something like:

```
function scriviElenco(passa) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const wsd = ss.getSheetByName("morosi");
  // your existing implementation
}
```

and perhaps even a one-liner helper function such as:

```
function getSheet(sheetName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
}
```

which you assign to a constant at the beginning of each of the two functions.