# Functions accessible from different scripts but constants aren't when added via JQuery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a legacy system where an endpoint sends an HTML content that when received in the frontend is added to a div: `$('#some-div').html(htmlContent)`.

That works fine, but I am observing something strange, when I define some constants in a `<script>` they appear as undefined in the scripts that continue:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // This simulates the content retrieved from the server
  let contentFromBackend = JSON.parse("{\"text\":\"<script>\\n    const someConst = \'hello\'\\n\\n    function someConstFn() {\\n        return \'hello\'\\n    }\\n<\/script>\\n\\n<script>\\n    console.log(someConstFn()) \/\/ This works!\\n    console.log(someConst) \/\/ This fails saying that someConst is undefined!\\n<\/script>\"}")['text']

  // Appends to div
  $('#some-div').html(contentFromBackend)
})
</script>

<div id="some-div"><div>
```

If the content is generated statically (for example, with a Template Renderer like Twig or plain HTML) both the constant and the functions work perfectly. **`var` also works fine**. Why does this happen?

Comment: Turned your example into a snippet (so we can run it) it works. I see "hello" twice

Comment: Your code works as intended. Maybe your code is actually different? E.g. you first log it and only then define?

Comment: Because the snippet is not retrieved from a Symfony backend and appended with JQuery to an existing div

Comment: Does this answer your question? [const keyword scope in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272836/const-keyword-scope-in-javascript)

Comment: @Genarito So show us how you get that script.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so @Justinas as const scope works fine when the content is static (like the snippet). I've worked in projects with React where several const are defined in different scripts in the HTML and the transpiled code can access them perfectly. This doesn't happen with JQuery append

Comment: And changing `const` to `var`?

Comment: `var` works! Wtf!? I'll edit and add and simulated example later to get my point. Thanks @Nat

Comment: @JeremyThille, Justinas. I've added a simulated example. Check that the second 'hello' is never printed... Please, don't downvote as the question is not answered in the proposed link...

Comment: @Justinas check the above comment. I can only tag one user per comment

Comment: @Genarito it was probably downvoted (before I even saw it) because the code *provided* did not demonstrate the problem described, at the time (and not everyone notices when someone else has converted it to a (non-demonstrable) snippet - so might have been ok without the snippet, but that just confirmed it didn't show the issue (as provided)

Comment: This is actually a really interesting issue!  Can confirm that changing  `const` to `var` in the json payload makes it work correctly.  I assume this is something to do with `const` being  ES6 but I don't really understand why appending it into the DOM would fall back to ES5

Comment: @Genarito a vote up to useful comments always helps new contributors like me :)

Comment: Sorry! Done, thanks!