# why do other charts on my webpage are not showing eventho there is no syntax error in PhP and charts.js?

Tags: chart.js

I made a dashboard on my website that has **3 different visualization charts**, the data is from my database, and the problem that I'm encountering is that the other two are **not showing** eventhough the first one shows itself. moreover, if I **hide or remove** the first chart, the second one appears, but the third one still doesn't show.  refer to images below:

[First Chart Shows the following two are not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SNIJ.png)

[The second chart only shows itself when I delete the code of the first chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhbC5.png)

[The 3rd chart is the same case as 2nd, needed to remove the first and second charts just to see the third one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGdxu.png)

here is my code:

```
<!--CHARTS-->
<!--BAR CHART-->
<div class="container-fluid px-4">
<?php 
// Attempt select query execution
try{
  $barsql = "SELECT * FROM castro_rentals.unit";   
  $barresult = $pdo->query($barsql);
  if($barresult->rowCount() > 0) {
    $price = array();
    $unit_no = array();

    while($row = $barresult->fetch()) {
        $price[] = $row["price"];
        $unit_no[] = $row["unit_no"];
    }

  unset($barresult);
  } else {
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e){
  die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $barsql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>


<div class="card mb-4">
                            <!--BAR CHART-->
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fas fa-chart-bar me-1"></i>
                                Unit Prices
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <canvas id="myBarChart" width="100%" height="50"></canvas>
                                </div>
                                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
                                <script>
                                    //SETUP BLOCK
                                    const price = <?php echo json_encode($price); ?>;
                                    const unit_no = <?php echo json_encode($unit_no); ?>;
                                    const data = {
                                    labels: unit_no,
                                      datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Price',
                                        data: price,
                                        backgroundColor: ['rgba(57, 43, 90, .6)'],
                                        borderColor:'rgb(57, 43, 90)',
                                        borderWidth: 2
                                    }]
                                  };
                                    //CONFIG BLOCK
                                    const config = {
                                    type: 'bar',
                                    data,
                                    options: {
                                      scales: {
                                        y: {
                                          beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                };
                                    //RENDER BLOCK
                                    const myBarChart = new Chart(
                                        document.getElementById('myBarChart'),
                                        config
                                        );
                                </script>
                            <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
</div>

        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <!--LINE CHART-->
                                <?php 
                                include('config/dbcon.php');
                                // Attempt select query execution
                                try{
                                  $linesql = "SELECT * FROM castro_rentals.payment";   
                                  $lineresult = $pdo->query($linesql);
                                  if($lineresult->rowCount() > 0) {
                                    $amount = array();
                                    $paymentdate = array();

                                    while($row = $lineresult->fetch()) {
                                        $amount[] = $row["amount"];
                                        $paymentdate[] = $row["paymentdate"];
                                    }

                                  unset($lineresult);
                                  } else {
                                    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
                                  }
                                } catch(PDOException $e){
                                  die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $linesql. " . $e->getMessage());
                                }
                                 
                                // Close connection
                                unset($pdo);
                                ?>
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-line me-1"></i>
                                        Monthly Income
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <canvas id="myLineChart" width="100%" height="50"></canvas>
                                        </div>
                                        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
                                <script>
                                    //SETUP BLOCK
                                    const amount = <?php echo json_encode($amount); ?>;
                                    const paymentdate = <?php echo json_encode($paymentdate); ?>;
                                    const data = {
                                    labels: paymentdate,
                                      datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Amount',
                                        data: amount,
                                        backgroundColor: ['rgba(57, 43, 90, .6)'],
                                        borderColor:'rgb(57, 43, 90)',
                                        borderWidth: 2
                                    }]
                                  };
                                    //CONFIG BLOCK
                                    const config = {
                                    type: 'line',
                                    data,
                                    options: {
                                      scales: {
                                        y: {
                                          beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                };
                                    //RENDER BLOCK
                                    const myLineChart = new Chart(
                                        document.getElementById('myLineChart'),
                                        config
                                        );
                                </script>
                                    <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--PIE CHART-->
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <!--PIE CHART-->
<?php 
include('config/dbcon.php');
// Attempt select query execution
try{
  $piesql = "SELECT * FROM castro_rentals.property";   
  $pieresult = $pdo->query($piesql);
  if($pieresult->rowCount() > 0) {
    $propertyname = array();
    $paymentdate = array();

    while($row = $pieresult->fetch()) {
        $propertyname[] = $row["propertyname"];
        $propertytype[] = $row["propertytype"];
    }

  unset($pieresult);
  } else {
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e){
  die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $piesql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-pie me-1"></i>
                                        # of Property Type
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <canvas id="myPieChart" width="100%" height="50"></canvas>
                                        </div>
                                        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
                                <script>
                                    //SETUP BLOCK
                                    const propertyname = <?php echo json_encode($propertyname); ?>;
                                    const propertytype = <?php echo json_encode($propertytype); ?>;
                                    const data = {
                                    labels: propertytype,
                                      datasets: [{
                                        label: 'propertyname',
                                        data: propertyname,
                                        backgroundColor: ['rgba(57, 43, 90, .6)'],
                                        borderColor:'rgb(57, 43, 90)',
                                        borderWidth: 2
                                    }]
                                  };
                                    //CONFIG BLOCK
                                    const config = {
                                    type: 'pie',
                                    data,
                                    options: {
                                      scales: {
                                        y: {
                                          beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                };
                                    //RENDER BLOCK
                                    const myPieChart = new Chart(
                                        document.getElementById('myPieChart'),
                                        config
                                        );
                                </script>
                                    <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The only thing I tried to do is to play with the <div> before the <canvas> I thought it wouldn't show because of spacing and size problems but I tried modifying, removing, resizing them, it still didn't show.

Comment: Could you try to rename your `const` variables foreach chart. Seems you are creating global variables for config and data, which can't be changed afterwards. see [const keyword scope in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272836/const-keyword-scope-in-javascript)

Comment: You repeat things that don't need repeating, like `include('config/dbcon.php');` and `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>`. Do them once, at the start of your script.

Comment: As soon as you start repeating the same, or similar, code you should try to use a function, so you only use that code once. See: [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I tried removing the redundant 'include('config/dbcon.php'); and <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>' 

The first chart is still showing but I received an error "Warning: Undefined variable $pdo on line 175" and "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null" can you tell me how use a function? I'm quite new to these stuffs.

Comment: Don't use `unset($pdo);`, it causes the error, and is not needed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware here are the codes from line 173 to 178: '' try{
                                  $linesql = "SELECT * FROM castro_rentals.payment";   
                                  $lineresult = $pdo->query($linesql);
                                  if($lineresult->rowCount() > 0) {
                                    $amount = array();
                                    $paymentdate = array(); ''

Comment: There are many good tutorials out there to learn about functions. For instance: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_functions.htm

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I did what you told me, I removed all the unset($pdo); and the errors were removed, also removed the redundancies but we're back at square one where it still doesn't show the two charts.

Comment: @definitelynotaprogrammer that is because of my comment. You are creating JavaScript `const` variables. These can't be overwritten later. Try to rename your JS variables for each chart --- or use `var` instead of `const` --- or create a custom scope [see const MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: @Uwe that worked! changing from const to var fixed it! thank you so much!

Comment: Nice. You should read the two links I wrote in my comments to understand why it happened.

Comment: @Uwe will do!!!